# Angular onSameUrlNavigation for a lazy loaded module

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have a problem with lazy loaded module data re-fetch.
onSameUrlNavigation  simply doesn't work

I have a separate routing module for a lazy loaded feature and maybe I couldn't integrate onSameUrlNavigation  properly

project structure:

```
app/
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
    app-routing.module.ts
        someFeature/
            someFeature.module.ts
            someFeature-routes.module.ts
            someFeature.component.ts
```

app-routing module code:

```js
    export const routes: Routes = [{
      {
      path: 'myfeature',
      loadChildren: () => import('./someFeature/someFeature.module').then(m => m.someFeatureModule),
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    }}]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

lazy loaded routing module:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: someFeatureComponent,
      },
    ];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
```

component code:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
    this.route
      .queryParams.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
      map(p => {
        this.loading = true;
        if (p.page && p.limit) {
          this.page = p.page;
          this.limit = p.limit;
        }
        return {
          page: this.page,
          limit: this.limit,
        };
      }),
      flatMap((f) => this.myService.getData(f)),
      tap(() => this.loading = false),
    )
      .subscribe((payload) => {
        this.data = payload.data;
      })
    ;
  }
```

this is the problematic section (in the component code)

```
 reload(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['someFeature'], {queryParams: {page: this.page, limit: this.limit}});
  }
refetchDataOnClick(){
 this.reload();
}
```

data is fetched on the first request (So I decided that there's no problem with module import or anything like that), but re-fetch isn't happening as I can see there are no additional requests on the API.

I tried adding and removing "runGuardsAndResolvers" ,someFeature-routes module, but with no success.
I also tried adding onSameUrlNavigation to someFeature-routes module, but forChild can accept only one parameter

Comment: Why do you want to re-fetch the data by navigating to the same component? You could just call `this.myService.getData(f)` again.

Comment: Thanks. that's actually a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the user [frido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9423231/frido)'s comment I found a solution

instead of reloading the component I just call the service which loads the data again

```
this.loading = true;
    this.myService.getData({page: this.page, limit: this.limit})
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        finalize(() => this.loading = false))
      .subscribe((payload) => {
        this.data = payload.data;
      });
```